# Adding a column to a dataframe in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I have the following dataframe (`df`)

```
 start     end
1    14379   32094
2   151884  174367
3   438422  449382
4   618123  621256
5   698271  714321
6   973394  975857
7   980508  982372
8   994539  994661
9  1055151 1058824
.   .       .
.   .       .
.   .       .
```

And a long vector with numeric values (`vec`).

I would like to add to each row another column, with the mean of the values in the corresponding places in `vec`. for example, the first row will have `mean(vec[14379:32094])`. I have tried playing with `transform` but wasn't able to accomplish this simple task.

Comment: I'm with one foot outside the office and can't come up with an example so fast, but FWIW, see ?apply.

Answer (score 71, accepted):

That is a pretty standard use case for `apply()`:

```
R> vec <- 1:10
R> DF <- data.frame(start=c(1,3,5,7), end=c(2,6,7,9))
R> DF$newcol <- apply(DF,1,function(row) mean(vec[ row[1] : row[2] ] ))
R> DF
  start end newcol
1     1   2    1.5
2     3   6    4.5
3     5   7    6.0
4     7   9    8.0
R>
```

You can also use `plyr` if you prefer but here is no real need to go beyond functions from base R.

Comment: +1 Thanks! Re. `plyr` - how can I use it if I want each row to be treated by itself?

Comment: What are you talking about? This treats each by itself.  How else would it do this?

Comment: each what? as far as I understand, `plyr` work on group of rows.

Answer (score 1):

Even if that's a 7 years old question, people new to R should consider using the [data.table](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table), package.

A data.table is a data.frame so all you can do for/to a data.frame you can also do. But many think are ORDERS of magnitude faster with data.table.

```
vec <- 1:10
library(data.table)
DT <- data.table(start=c(1,3,5,7), end=c(2,6,7,9))
DT[,new:=apply(DT,1,function(row) mean(vec[ row[1] : row[2] ] ))]
```

Comment: not sure why on earth I got downvoted here... ridiculous