# Filtering a dataframe in R

Tags: r, filter, dataframe

I have the following dataframe (`df`)

```
 start     end
1    14379   32094
2   151884  174367
3   438422  449382
4   618123  621256
5   698271  714321
6   973394  975857
7   980508  982372
8   994539  994661
9  1055151 1058824
.   .       .
.   .       .
.   .       .
```

And a long boolean vector with **boolean** values (`vec`).

I would like to filter out all ranges in `df` that contain at least one `TRUE` value in the corresponding locations in `vec`.

In other words, a row with `start=x` `end=y` will be outputted iff `!any(vec[x:y])`.

Any ideas on how to accomplish that?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Adding a column to a dataframe in R](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3651651/adding-a-column-to-a-dataframe-in-r)

Comment: @hadley how is that a duplicate? I used the same dataframe but the question is different (filtering a dataframe vs. adding columns to a dataframe).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is the same question as:
[Adding a column to a dataframe in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3651651/adding-a-column-to-a-dataframe-in-r)
so it has the same answer... use apply, but with `any` instead of `mean`...

```
> ranges <- apply(DF,1,function(row) !any(vec[ row[1]:row[2] ]))
> DF[ranges,]
```

Answer (score 2):

I have read your other posts about this topic, if you want to achieve this with `plyr`, 
try this:

```
new.df <- adply(df, .margins=1, function(x){if(!any(vec[x$start:x$end])) return(x)})
```